# Build a Snap for C Makefile project

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

We are using DELL Edge Gateway 3001 having Ubuntu Core 16 OS.

We need to create a Snap for our C Makefile project code.

Request to provide some example Snap for building from C code, we are using gcc, libsqlite3-dev, libcurl4-gnutls-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at https://snapcraft.io/  , and the 'build your first snap' ...

Answer (score 2):

The language guides are a good start, there is one for c/c++ using `autotools`, but in most cases it should be trivial to swap it for `cmake` if needed.

This is the guide https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/c

In any case, here is a domain specific guide for MOOS which makes use of `cmake` https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/moos which can be used as reference for the `snapcraft.yaml` specific syntax.